# exclude password column in query sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I need to know how to query by excluding password column.
is it possible?

```
query = await db.execute(
        select(User)
        .filter(User.id.in_(users.user_ids)).where(User.is_deleted== False))
    list_user = query.scalars().unique().all()
```

Comment: Generally you'd implement this by having a `response_model` in your API layer in FastAPI where the password field isn't included - meaning that the password hash never gets returned to the user. As far as I know there is no option in SQLAlchemy to exclude a column, so you'd have to loop over all available columns and include those that doesn't match your exclusion. But the common solution is to use a proper response model w/Pydantic which defines what gets returned instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "Deferred Column Loading" feature. For example, if you want the `password` column to be loaded only upon direct access, instead of when the entity is queried, you can define it using the `deferred` function in your model:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import deferred
from sqlalchemy import String, Column, ...


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    username = Column(String(200), nullable=False)
    ...
    password = deferred(Column(String(2000)))
    ...
```

Comment: I defined  **deferred**  in my model and the problem was solved.thank you very much indeed